# Retrieving current angular app name dynamically: is that possible?

Tags: angular

I know it's a strage request but I'd like to send my app name inside of an HTTP header for each http request.

In order to do so I have already written an interceptor, but now I need to dynamically get the app's name. So, say that I create a "my-app" name how can I retrieve it in my code?

The "dynamically" part is very important: suppose I have more than one app (microfrontend): I need to make sure that the app name is different between them.

Answer (score 1):

**Application name**

You can use Angular DI providers to achieve that. Details https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-an-injectiontoken-object

1. Create injection token for application name.

```js
export const APP_NAME = new InjectionToken<string>('APP_NAME')
```

2. Add it to the providers list in AppModule and specify your app name.

```js
@NgModule({
...
    providers: [
        { provide: APP_NAME, useValue: 'my-app' }
    ]
...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3. Inject it to your interceptor and use it.

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(@Inject(APP_NAME) private appName: string) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(this.appName);
        ...
    }

}
```

**Module name**

Note, this solution is working for lazy modules. But it also should work for remote modules.

1. Specify name of the module in route's data property.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: 'feature',
        loadChildren: () => import('./feature/feature.module').then(m => m.FeatureModule),
        data: { moduleName: 'feature-name' },
    },
    ...
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

2. Now module name can be resolved using [Router#routerState](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#routerState).

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler,): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const moduleName = this.getModuleName();
        console.log(moduleName); 

        return next.handle(req);
    }

    private getModuleName(): string | null {
        const rootRoute = this.router.routerState.root.firstChild;
        if (!rootRoute) {
            return null;
        }

        return rootRoute.snapshot.data.moduleName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the inject "dynamic"? Suppose I have a shared interceptor class but I want to change the app name according to the module it's using it? (I'm using webpack module federation)

Comment: The main question was about app's name. So please extend your question with these details. I'll add update.

Comment: Edited let me know!